Cross Compiling QT window linux
I have a Qt project on Windows, and I successfully added a Linux device, establishing a connection. However, when attempting to configure the kit, it seems that the Qt version is not compatible. Which Qt version should I use instead?
i tried many versions but it seems that none of that worked
